# using awk to find lines in file1 than don't have matches in file2

Tags: awk

file1 contains a list of charges from my credit card:

```
A            B
1/1/2020     $12.50
1/3/2020     $10.00
1/5/2020     $99.15
1/6/2020     $35.50
1/8/2020     $99.00
```

file2 contains a list of legitimate purchases, the dates don't necessarily match but the amounts in column B should match

```
A            B
12/31/2020   $12.50
1/4/2020     $99.15
1/6/2020     $99.00
```

Using column B to match, how do I find the records in file1 that don't have matching records in file2?

```
A            B
1/3/2020     $10.00
1/6/2020     $35.50
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F'$' '
  FNR==NR{ if (FNR>1){ a[$2]++} next }
  $2 in a && a[$2]{ a[$2]--; next }
  1
' file2 file1
```

Save the values of `file2` in an array and increment a counter skipping the header line. Continue with the next line.

When `file1` is processed, test if the corresponding value exists in the array and the counter is non-zero.
If that's the case, decrement the counter and continue with the next line.

Else, print the current line.

Comment: awesome thanks for the explanation and formatting made it super easy to understand!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{cnt[$2]++; next} (FNR==1) || (--cnt[$2] < 0)' file2 file1
A            B
1/3/2020     $10.00
1/6/2020     $35.50
```

Comment: thanks! seems too easy when you write it like that!

Comment: Like the pre-decrement to the counter to avoid one test. Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

OK so this is non `awk` and is a little untidy but it gives a little more info about the matches

```
join -a 2 -j 2 <(sort -k 2 legit) <(sort -k 2 charged)
```

and an `awk` variant of the others above

```
awk 'NR==FNR{legit[$2]++; next}{legit[$2]--}legit[$2]<0{legit[$2]=0; print}' legit charged
```

Comment: I didn't consider using join, use the simplest tool right? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

command

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}!($2 in a){print $0}' file2 file1
```

output

```
1/3/2020     $10.00
1/6/2020     $35.50
```